# How to see the date that Salesforce license was assigned to an user?

Tags: licenses

I have been scrolling a lot, and I would like to know if there's a way to know the date of the license assignment, i. e. to see if I provide a Salesforce license on july 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is the user's Created Date. However it is possible that you upgraded the user from one license type to another. In that case you might find info on that in Setup Audit Trail if it happened in the last 6 months.